# Setting custom Class Path while executing mvn exec:java

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I have a simple use case of running a main method from a jar . This jar get created as a part of  mvn packge and gets stored in myproject/target/myproject-jar-withdependencies

How i am running it right now is using a simple java -cp {path-to -jar} {mainclass} . I am trying to use mvn exec plugin for this but am having problems running it

The crux is that i need to force maven to find the main class inside a jar that is in target/
directory . I tried using -cp and jar using the argument tag but unfortunately that doesnt work either . Maven doesnt seem to recognize the jars inside the target directory as belonging to the class path

I need to specify the custom classpath in the exec plugin (the docs in mvn exec dont give much information to this)

Any pointers is much appreciated

Comment: You cannot use `-cp` with jars. All the classpath must be in jar file itself.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak Ok, obviously I didn't make myself clear. I meant to say that you can't use `-cp` option when launching java program like this: `java -jar a.jar`.

Comment: Please add your pom which show how you configured the maven exec plugin otherwise it's impossible to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Sorry about the very late update. But this is fixed. My pom was misconfigured

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

> Sorry about the very late update. But this is fixed. My pom was
>   misconfigured –  Nitin Feb 8 '13 at 23:47